# XML deserialize enum value with XmlEnumAttribute Name=" "

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, enums, xmlserializer

I was provided with a XML schema and used xsd.exe to generate classes from it. One of the clasees is enum type that looks like this:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.17929")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public enum MyType
{

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("+Test")]
    Test,

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute(" ")]
    Item,

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("  ")]
    Item1,

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("   ")]
    Item2,

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("    ")]
    Item3,
}
```

When I serialize a class that uses this enum with value e.g. Item1, I get expected behavior and the element looks like:

```
<MyType> </MyType>
```

The problem is when I try to deserialize the XML using XmlSerializer's Deserialize method. The method does not throw any exception, but the enum value isn't expected **Item1** but **Test**.

Any help of how could I get this working? Preferrably without modifying the generated code?

Thanks

UPDATE:

The code used for deserialization:

```
    public static T Deserialize<T>(string xml, Type[] extraTypes = null)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xml))
        {
            return default(T);
        }

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), extraTypes);
        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        using (StringReader textReader = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(textReader, settings))
            {
                return (T)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
            }
        }
    }
```

The method is called like this:

```
var result = Deserialize<MyType>(content);
```

Comment: can you post the code for deserialization?

Comment: @RajeshSubramanian question updated with code for deserialization

Comment: It might be taking the default value as you are directly returning the object ..try using Enum.Parse while returning

Comment: @RajeshSubramanian The Enum.Parse is a no go here, as it does not take into consideration the XmlEnumAttribute and thus is working for values like "Test" or "Item" but throws exception when parsing values such as " " or "+Test" which is what I need to parse. Of course I could use reflection in order to get the value of the XmlEnumAttribute and its Name property and parse the value like this, I just think that something like this should work directly via deserialization process.